# Rectangles render with gaps in between them (Box2D)

Tags: c++, box2d

Right now I create my boxes where 1 meter is 85 pixels. Gravity is 10.  And

```
                        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.1f;
            fixtureDef.friction = 0.5f;
            fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
```

The problem I'm having is illustrated in the image I have provided:
[image: http://www.box2d.org/forum/download/file.php?mode=view&id=1044&sid=86e8772dc965cba215f9a16cca2839e4]

As you can see, there is a small gap between many, but not all the crates. What could cause this?

Thanks

Comment: You have a graphical error so you post a question about your physics engine instead of the graphics engine?

Comment: You need anti-aliasing

Comment: No I do not need it.

Comment: @Milo yeah you do. It would most likely fix the problem.

Comment: So if you don't use box2d stuff, and you render the boxes on top of another, then there is no such gap?

Comment: Antiaiasing the scene only fixed jagged edges, not the gaps. By making my boxes slightly smaller in Box2D it fixed it but it feels like a hack to do this.

Comment: Yes, it's cheating, but so is the entire physics engine. Who cares, it works.  "If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck" :p

Comment: But what about polygons, that means I need to multiply every coordinate too, and it might be tricky in a level editor to do it right. I hate hacks -_-'

Comment: No why? Only the physical representation is scaled a little bit smaller, all the rest remains the same.

Comment: Bullet does the same btw. for all bodies, a physics simulation is full of simplifications, thats what makes it feasable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess that's some issue in box2d, there is such a bug to increase performance. since more accuracy needs much more computational power. to fix that issue I guess you only need reduce box physical sizes (for example you can create a 84px*84px rectangle for a 86px*86px image). you can also fade the pixels in the edges to get better results.

Comment: Many physics engines use a small cheat distance and especially for when objects come to rest.  Your oversize rectangle would make a nice fix, I'll wager.

Comment: Box2d does, in fact, use a small 'cheat distance', and that's probably what's causing the boxes to not-quite-touch. The extra space around objects is so that floating point precision errors don't make items penetrate.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say that Ali is right, Box2D has a macro on this - I'll paste it here:

```
/// The radius of the polygon/edge shape skin. This should not be modified. Making
/// this smaller means polygons will have an insufficient buffer for continuous collision.
/// Making it larger may create artifacts for vertex collision.
#define b2_polygonRadius        (2.0f * b2_linearSlop)
```

This value is assigned to a new b2PolygonShape's m_radius field in the constructor. Subtracting this value from your body during creation is a trivial solution to resolve the gap glitch:

```
    b2PolygonShape polygon;
    polygon.SetAsBox(width*0.5-polygon.m_radius, height*0.5-polygon.m_radius, b2Vec2(offsetX, offsetY), angle);
    fixture.shape = &polygon;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also documented in the manual http://box2d.org/manual.pdf :

> 4.2 Shapes
>
> Polygons inherit a radius from b2Shape. The radius creates a skin around the polygon. The skin is used in
>   stacking scenarios to keep polygons slightly separated. This allows continuous collision to work against
>   the core polygon.
>
> The polygon skin helps prevent tunneling by keeping the polygons separated. This results in small gaps
>   between the shapes. Your visual representation can be larger than the polygon to hide any gaps.

I have found that I can get better looking results simply by scaling up the scene, which makes the gaps look smaller, as it appears that the skin has a fixed width.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705095/webgl-box2d-drawing-issue-gap-between-bodies